# Divisors of a number with exactly 4 divisors

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a number n (0 < n < 2 * 10^18), and I am given that it has exactly 4 divisors.

Is there a way I could get those divisors faster than O(sqrt(n)) ?

Using a classical algorithm to find divisors of a number ([link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-factors-of-a-natural-number/)) takes O(sqrt(n)) time. sqrt(2*10^18) is around 10^9 and it would take too much time.

Also a number with exactly 4 divisors is a product of two different prime numbers, or a cube of a prime number.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249377/discussion-on-question-by-jukasz-lewandowski-divisors-of-a-number-with-exactly-4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pollard's rho method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) is simple, and takes expected O(sqrt(sqrt(n)) time.  sqrt(sqrt(10<sup>18</sup>)) is < 32000, so quite fast for numbers in that range.

Answer (score -2):

Big O gives you the complexity of the algorithm. It doesn't give you the amount of time it takes to calculate it.

If your number is 10^18, an O(sqrt(n)) algorithm doesn't take 10^9 seconds to complete. It'll take ~10^9 iterations to complete.

CPUs are very fast. They can execute 10^9 instructions per second.

Factoring the 18 digit number 600851475143123457 into the factors 3, 11 and 18207620458882529 in C# took 720ms and 480ms in C++ (not multithreaded, Ryzen 7 CPU, Release builds). Please specify how that "would take too much time." What performance requirements do you have?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @EricPostpischil and I'm not sure if the question that was asked is the question OP needs to be answered. I think there's a misunderstanding on OPs side, so I'll leave my answer here.